# Android lint fails on Gitlab Runner (Docker)

Tags: android, docker, groovy, gitlab

I have a Gitlab runner (Docker Executor) that runs the Android `lintDevDebug` task. The Gitlab runner is running on GCP. The job fails while trying to download `groovy-all-2.4.15.jar`. I can `wget` the jar file in the .gitlab-ci.yml file in the same lint job and there's no connection issue there. I get the same issue while using `jCenter()` to get the jar. The `lineDevDebug` works without any issue on local machines. The other tasks in the `.gitlab-ci-yml` work without any issues on the CI (e.g. `assembleDebug` etc). Any help would be highly appreciated.

The error is:

```
> Task :app:lintDevDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintDevDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
            > Connection reset
```

Here's the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: ghcr.io/alvr/alpine-android:latest-jdk8

before_script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build
  - test

lintDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew --info -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDevDebug -PbuildDir=lint
  tags:
    - android-runner
```

Comment: This looks like a possible network issue. Are you sure that your gitlab runners don't have some firewall rules that forbid them from accessing those repositories?

Comment: @theUndying I inserted a debug step in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and did a `wget -c https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar`. It downloaded the file without issues. This should prove that the runners have access and can download the file without issues.

Comment: I guess you can try with different gradle versions then. It sounds like it's possible to be coming from gradle's and whatever it's using for http client. This "connection reset" is weird.